# Stacking, adjust the probabilities to new data should improve accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, stacking

I'm looking for some expert opinion on what to expect when using the output from model A (probabilities) as input into model B.

I have a population where all instances have been assigned a probability from model A. I checked how the model has performed over time using the actual data from target variable and got a roc auc score of X.

Now I want to train a new model, model B on that dataset, using as input the probabilities from model A and as target variable the actual target outcome. Nothing else.

I would expect model B to outperform model A because I train the old probabilities on the actual data. But the roc auc score for model B gets a bit lower than for model A.  (Both LogisticRegression)

Is this reasonable? I know I don't provide any reproducible example; I'm looking for a reasoning more than a solution.

Any thoughts on my predicaments would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The AUC shouldn't be affected at all: model B, being a logistic regression, is a monotone transformation of the outputs from model A, so the rank-ordering is preserved (or reversed, in the pathological case where B actually assigns a negative coefficient to A's probabilities, in which case the AUC will be the complement).  Are you scoring on the same dataset?

Comment: No, the dataset is different.

Comment: There can be no guarantee then; scores on different datasets may differ just due to the differences in the data.

Comment: Yes, that make sense. However, I think it's a bit strange that the assigns probabilities from model A doesn't improve when training on actual data.